# SysVar in C# COM with CANoe

Tags: c#, com, canoe, system-variable

I'm trying to communicate in C# with CANoe but I get some errors.

I have this setup to Open and Start (⚡) CANoe APP, and it is working fine:

```
private CANoe.Application CANoeApp;
private void buttonOpenStartCanoe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       CANoeApp = (CANoe.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("CANoe.Application");
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        CANoeApp = new CANoe.Application();
    }
}
```

Now **I would like to modify and read the values from System Variables**, I have tried several options I found on internet bute none of them worked.
The namespace *"Debug"* is where my variable is, and the name of my variable is *"Target_Level_ALL"*.

If someone knows how to modify System Variables in Canoe from C# would be really helpfull because I have already tried very different codes and none is working.

**Some of the codes I already tried are below:**

1. Here the problem was the GetSysVar was not availiable in LINBus:

```
CANoe.Application CANoeApp = (CANoe.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("CANoe.Application");
CANoe.Measurement measurement = CANoeApp.Measurement;

CANoe.Bus LINBus = CANoeApp.get_Bus("LIN");
CANoe.Variable sysVar = LINBus.GetSysVar("Debug", "Target_Level_ALL");
sysVar.Value = 100;
```

2. I tried using .Configurations method but was neither available:

```
measurement.Configurations.System.SysVar["Debug.Target_Level_ALL"].Value = 100;
```

3. Same issue if I try to use directly SysVar from the Application object

```
CANoeApp.SysVar["Debug.Target_Level_ALL"].Value = 100;
```

4. I tried using canoe.system.system but with same result, not working

```
Canoe.System.System system = new Canoe.System.System();

system.SetVariableValue("Debug.Target_Level_ALL", 100);
```

**Update:** I'm trying with this new code but still not finding the System Variable in the environment of CANoe: (TableSel is my NameSpace and Target_Color is my variable)

```
CANoe.Environment CANoeEnvironment = CANoe.Environment)CANoeApp.Environment;

CANoe.EnvironmentVariable envVar = (CANoe.EnvironmentVariable)CANoeEnvironment.GetVariable("TableSel.Target_Color");

object value = envVar.Value;

envVar.Value = 3;
```

**Any help will be very well received :)
Thanks and have a nice day**

Answer (score 0):

little update,
**I found a document from Vector and I have modified some lines to succeed to read the CAnoe System Variables with the next code lines:**

```
CANoe.System CANoeSystem = (CANoe.System)CANoeApp.System;
CANoe.Namespaces CANoeNamespaces = (CANoe.Namespaces)CANoeSystem.Namespaces;
CANoe.Namespace CANoeNamespaceGeneral = (CANoe.Namespace)CANoeNamespaces["Debug"];
CANoe.Variables CANoeVariablesGeneral = (CANoe.Variables)CANoeNamespaceGeneral.Variables;
CANoe.Variable sysVar = (CANoe.Variable)CANoeVariablesGeneral["Target_Level"];
Console.WriteLine($"Value Target_Level: " + sysVar.Value);
```

**And these ones to edit the system variable:**

```
CANoe.Measurement CANoeMeasurement = (CANoe.Measurement)CANoeApp.Measurement;
CANoe.Namespace CANoeNamespaceDebug = (CANoe.Namespace)CANoeNamespaces["Debug"];
CANoe.Variables CANoeVariablesDebug = (CANoe.Variables)CANoeNamespaceDebug.Variables;
CANoe.Variable sysVarTargetLevel = (CANoe.Variable)CANoeVariablesDebug["Target_Level"];
sysVarTargetLevel.Value = 20;
```

I hope I could help someone in the future with this information.